R quarto kableExtra row background color
I'm making a Quarto HTML document, and I would like to change the background colors in table rows. I'm using kableExtra, and the rows are colored as I expect when I run an individual code chunk in RStudio, but when I knit the document, the row colors are different. The knit document appears to color every other row slightly darker and then add my colors over top. How can I prevent the knit document from changing the colors that I specify?
Output from running an individual chunk:

Output in the knit document:

Row 1 is darker than row 2; row 90 is darker than row 91; row 101 is darker than row 102.
---
pagetitle: "my title"
title:  my title
author: author
date:   today
format:
  html:
    code-fold: true
    code-summary: "Show the code"
    code-tools: true
    df-print: kable
    toc: true
    toc-location: left
    toc-depth: 3
    toc-expand: true
    number-sections: true
    theme: readable
    page-layout: full
    self-contained: true
---

```{r}
library(tidyverse)

# define a function to create kable tables
my_kable_table <- function(data, 
                           column_names = NULL, 
                           column_alignment = NULL, 
                           header_alignment = "center"){
  data %>%
    knitr::kable(
      # Disable Quarto table processing (https://examples.quarto.pub/opt-out-table-processing-kable/)
      table.attr = "quarto-disable-processing=true",
      format = "html",
      right = FALSE,
      col.names = {if(is.null(column_names)) names(data) else column_names},
      align = column_alignment,
      escape = FALSE # allow direct insertion of HTML
    ) %>%
    kableExtra::kable_styling(
      bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive", "bordered"),
      full_width = F
    ) %>%
    kableExtra::row_spec(
      row = 0, 
      align = header_alignment
    )
}
```

```{r}
#| label: tbl-1
#| tbl-cap: "my table."

table_data <- iris[c(1:2, 90:91,101:102),]

background_colors <- c(
  "setosa"     = "pink",
  "versicolor" = "white",
  "virginica"  = "skyblue"
  )

my_kable_table(
  data = table_data, 
  column_names = c("Sepal<br>Length", 
                   "Sepal<br>Width",
                   "Petal<br>Length",
                   "Petal<br>Width",
                   "Species"),
  column_alignment = "rrrrc"
) %>% 
  # set background color of row by subtype
  kableExtra::row_spec(
    row = which(table_data$Species == names(background_colors)[1]), 
    color = "black", 
    background = background_colors[1]) %>% 
  kableExtra::row_spec(
    row = which(table_data$Species == names(background_colors)[2]), 
    color = "black", 
    background = background_colors[2]) %>% 
  kableExtra::row_spec(
    row = which(table_data$Species == names(background_colors)[3]), 
    color = "black", 
    background = background_colors[3])
```


I'm using R version 4.3.1
kableExtra 1.4.0

Did you try to remove the striped option from bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed", "responsive", "bordered")?

As usual, the computer was just doing what I told it to do. Convenient that it was just ignorant coding on my part. If you'd like to submit your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.
